# H2 JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement - INSERT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, h2, spring-boot-test

I'm getting this error to initialize my memory database with some data because my sql script to load the data is formatted wrong to H2:

```
INSERT INTO cup_orchestrator.cpo_environment (`environment_id`,`environment`)
VALUES
(
   1,
   'DEV'
),

(
   2,
   'ACT'
),

(
   3,
   'PRD'
);
```

And H2 expected on this way:

```
INSERT INTO cup_orchestrator.cpo_environment (`environment_id`,`environment`) VALUES(1,'DEV'),(2,'ACT'),(3,'PRD');
```

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO CUP_ORCHESTRATOR.CPO_ENVIRONMENT (`ENVIRONMENT_ID`,`ENVIRONMENT`)[*]"; expected "DIRECT, SORTED, DEFAULT, VALUES, SET, (, WITH, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO cup_orchestrator.cpo_environment (`environment_id`,`environment`)
```

Is there any plugin in Eclipse to format the sql script in the way that H2 expect? I'm using SQL Editor 1.1.0 but there is no option.

Comment: Your original multi-line command is perfectly valid for H2, you don't need to write it in a single line. You got such exception because you somehow passed only the first line to H2 instead of the whole command.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Is there any configuration for this? Because I did ctrl + c, ctrl + v from my sql editor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use that tool and can't help you with it. I just give you some information about your problem, because your assumption about H2's syntax was incorrect.

Comment: I have faced same problem. I solve it by putting a semicolon at the end of my SQL statement. Very strange.

Comment: @EmdadulSawon I have already a semicolon.

Comment: @AldoInáciodaSilva Try to write query in a sing line and put a semicolon at the end of line. I don't know what is the main cause, may be it will work.

Comment: @EmdadulSawon Is there any plugin in Eclipse to format the sql script in the way that H2 expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to IntelliJ 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) and solved.

Answer (score 1):

In the question posted there's a semi-colon, just in case you are like me found this page, **make sure end the SQL statement with ";"**. if you don't have a semi-colon to complete the SQL statement, you would get a same error.

Answer (score 0):

This must be syntax error. please remove the quotes from  column names (`environment_id`,`environment`) and try